# How to get system information in guest account c#?

Tags: c#, wmi, accounts

I would like to know how to get system information such as OS name and version, system manufacturer.

I can get this information by WMI queries, but WMI queries are not working for guest account.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

System.Environment class resolves most of your needs:

```
 System.Environment.OSVersion 
 System.Environment.ProcessorCount 
 System.Environment.MachineName
```